# Error: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm attempting to allow my user to be able to delete/remove a row from a tableView (remove an object from an existing NSMutableArray), however when I try and delete the row, I get the following crash error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray
>   removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Does anyone know why this might be? See code below. Apologies for the lengthy code.

**.h**

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *descripData;
```

**.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.descripData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc]init];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refreshTable) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    NSMutableDictionary *viewParams = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [viewParams setValue:@"storeditems" forKey:@"view_name"];
    [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        self.descripData = responseObject;
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self.storageData count] > 0 && self.descripData.count > 0)
    {
        return [self.descripData count];
    }
    else
        return 0;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *DoctorsTableIdentifier = @"StorageItemTableViewCell";

    StorageItemTableViewCell *cell = (StorageItemTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:DoctorsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
        {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StorageItemTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

   if (self.storageData.count > 0 && self.descripData.count > 0) {
       noitemsView.hidden = YES;

       NSDictionary *title = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [[cell itemName] setText:[title objectForKey:@"node_title"]];

       NSDictionary *node = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [[cell itemDescrip] setText:[node objectForKey:@"body"]];
       NSDictionary *value = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [[cell valueLabel] setText:[value objectForKey:@"dollarvalue"]];
            NSLog(@"%@", self.descripData);

       NSDictionary *quantity = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       [[cell quantityLabel] setText:[quantity objectForKey:@"quantity"]];
       NSLog(@"%@", self.descripData);

       NSString *secondLink = [[self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"photo"];

       [cell.itemPhoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:secondLink]];
    }
    else {
        noitemsView.hidden = NO;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 152;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [self.descripData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ItemDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[ItemDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ItemDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    detailViewController.itemDetail = [[values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"node_title"];

    detailViewController.itemDetail = [self.descripData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    detailViewController.secondLink = self.descripData[indexPath.row][@"photo"];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Did you bother to actually read the exception message??

Comment: @HotLicks Of course I did. As my descripData property was set to be mutable, I wasn't sure why it was throwing me -that particular error-. Though your contribution to my legitimate question and obvious oversight is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the line `self.descripData = responseObject;`. It looks like you are probably setting your descripData property to point to a `NSArray`, not an `NSMutableArray`. If you really need the mutability, try `self.descripData = [responseObject mutableCopy];` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the following assignment causes the problem:

```
self.descripData = responseObject;
```

The response object itself is immutable, assigning it to a NSMutableArray does not change that fact, you need to create a NSMutableArray with the contents of the responseObject:

```
self.descripData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely happening on the following line:

```
self.descripData = responseObject;
```

You're replacing your previous mutable array for `descripData` with a new one, which apparently is not mutable. You can either create a new mutable array from this new array using `[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:responseObject]`, or you can add the contents of `responseObject` to your current mutable array.

It's important to pay attention when you assign something of type `id` to a variable, because there's no compile-time type checking that can occur. This sometimes results in errors at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Face this issue because NSUserDefaults always returns an immutable object.

```
Please while retrieving Mutable object from NSUserDefaults please refer below code.
NSMutableArray *storeArray = [[defaultDefects objectForKey:@"defaultStoreDefects"]mutableCopy];
```